# User access to FTP and at same time set www-data as owner/group

Tags: permissions, apache2, ftp

In order for wordpress to read/write the owner of the files/folders need to be www-data.

Now the problem is that if the owner is www-data of group filetransfer (www-data:filetransfer) then the FTP user ftpclient1 can login but does not have write permission to folders set to www-data:filetransfer because he's not the owner.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 7):

This guy [Tom](https://serverfault.com/users/17517/tom) deserves a medal for [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var)

Setting group ID the way he explains made it work!

> Attempting to expand on @Zoredache's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/6899/4276), as I give this a go
>   myself:
>
> - *Create a new group (www-pub) and add the users to that group*
>
>   ```
>   groupadd www-pub 
>   usermod -a -G www-pub usera    # must use -a to append to existing groups
>   usermod -a -G www-pub userb
>   groups usera    ## display groups for user
>   ```
> - *Change the ownership of everything under /var/www to root:www-pub*
>
>   ```
>   chown -R root:www-pub /var/www    # -R for recursive
>   ```
> - *Change the permissions of all the folders to 2775*
>
>   ```
>    chmod 2775 /var/www
>   ```
>
>   `2`=set group id, `7`=`rwx` for owner (root), `7`=`rwx` for group (www-pub), `5`=`rx` for world (including apache www-data
>     user)
>
>   Set group ID ([SETGID](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html)) bit (2) causes the group (www-pub) to be copied to all new files/folders created in that folder.  Other
>     options are SETUID (4) to copy the user id, and STICKY (1) which I
>     think lets only the owner delete files.
>
>   There's a `-R` recursive option, but that won't discriminate between files and folders, so you have to [use find](http://movabletripe.com/archive/recursively-chmod-directories-only/), like so:
>
>   ```
>   find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
>   ```
> - *Change all the files to 0664*
>
>   ```
>   find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
>   ```
> - *Change the umask for your users to 0002*
>
>   The umask controls the default file creation permissions, 0002 means files will have 664 and directories 775.  Setting this (by
>     editing the `umask` line at the bottom of `/etc/profile` in my case)
>     means files created by one user will be writable by other users in the
>     www-group without needing to `chmod` them.
>
> Test all this by creating a file and directory and verifying the
>   owner, group and permissions with `ls -l`.
>
> Note: You'll need to logout/in for changes to your groups to take
>   effect!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress was unable to create wp-config.php file after using above procedure.
I exectuted: chown -R root:www-data /var/www 
Then it worked.
Perhaps the user www-data (not the group with the same name) should be made member of www-pub group to have it working. I did not try the last option.